# class not found for all my photos after i did everything broke

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use the grid CSS (I'm very new to HTML/CSS) my goal is to make the photos is a 1fr 1fr 1fr grid. but only three of them work. as you can see lol. I'm following along with the video from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bMdjkfvONE&t=2629s I don't know anything else except. the code for content-wrapper / portfolio-item-wrapper / portfolio-img-background not sure why it broke it done it after I added the photos I don't know why to please any help would be so helpful.

```css
/* master styles */
.body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

/* NAV STYLES */
.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 38px;
}

.left-side {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-wrapper > .left-side > div {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-link-wrapper {
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a:hover {
    color: black;
}

/* portfolio styles */

.portfolio-items-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-side">
                <div class="brand">
                    <div> MICHAEL MULHOLLAND </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio1.jpg)">
                    </div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/crondose.png"
                        </div>

                        <div class="sybtitle">
                            portfolio colum 1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio2.jpg)">
                    </div>

                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/dailysmarty.png"
                        </div>

                        <div class="subtitle">
                        portfolio colum 2
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio3.jpg)">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/dashtrack.png" </div>
            
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 3
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
            
            </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio4.jpg)">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/devcamp.png" </div>
            
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 4
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
            
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio5.jpg)">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/devtrunk.png" </div>
            
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 5
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
            
            </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio6.jpg)">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/edutechional.png" </div>
            
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 6
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio7.jpg)">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/eventbrite.png" </div>
                
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 7
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio8.jpg)">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/ministry-safe.png" </div>
                
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 8
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio9.jpg)">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/open-devos.png" </div>
                
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 9
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio10.jpg)">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/quip.png" </div>
                
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 10
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio11.jpg)">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/shop-hacker.png" </div>
                
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 11
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio12.jpg)">
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo-wrapper">
                            <img src="images/logos/toastability.png" </div>
                
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                portfolio colum 12
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all you have several typos: your `<img src="..."` misses a closing `>`

Answer (score 0):

There are some wrong placed closing `</div>` and missing closing `>` on `<img>` tags.

For example, you are closing your `<div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">` which is the GRID container after closing the first `<div class="portfolio-item-wrapper"></div>`.

So I suggest you go through your code, check your DIV order and correct opening and closing of them.

Also you have to check your  tags, there are some closing `>` missing.

Then it will work.

I posted your code with the corrections below.

```css
/* master styles */
.body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

/* NAV STYLES */
.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 38px;
}

.left-side {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-wrapper > .left-side > div {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-link-wrapper {
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.nav-link-wrapper:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav-link-wrapper a:hover {
    color: black;
}

/* portfolio styles */

.portfolio-items-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>page title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
          <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <div class="brand">
          <div> MICHAEL MULHOLLAND </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio1.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/crondose.png">
            </div>

            <div class="sybtitle">
              portfolio colum 1
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>



        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio2.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/dailysmarty.png">
            </div>

            <div class="subtitle">
              portfolio colum 2
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>



        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio3.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/dashtrack.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 3
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio4.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/devcamp.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 4
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>


        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio5.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/devtrunk.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 5
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio6.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/edutechional.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 6
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio7.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/eventbrite.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 7
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio8.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/ministry-safe.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 8
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio9.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/open-devos.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 9
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio10.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/quip.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 10
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio11.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/shop-hacker.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 11
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio12.jpg)">
          </div>

          <div class="img-text-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
              <img src="images/logos/toastability.png">

              <div class="subtitle">
                portfolio colum 12
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
</body>

</html>
```